# Is it possible to make dropdown list in action bar full screen width?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Action bar dropdown list width by default depends on content size. (like there http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-iq8YXQBQjTo/TaXccBS9wZI/AAAAAAAAAVE/3NdspdF2eB4/s400/I2.png)

Is is possible to make it fullscreen width?

Comment: Check this answer, it may help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712697/actionbar-list-navigation-width-wrap-content