# Align spinner dropdown anchor by currently displayed items width

Tags: android, android-view, android-spinner

When using a `Spinner` Id love for my dropdown anchor to be displayed right next to the displayed item, rather than being far off in the distance. **Is this possible without creating a dropdown anchor myself and putting it in the `TextView` itself?**

For clarity: The black line in the image is the distance I would like to get rid off. It currently matches the longest item in the `Spinner` dropdown.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Are the other strings in the `Spinner` longer than the example given here i.e. Hips?

Comment: @howdoidothis Yup, thats the problem.

Comment: Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712697/actionbar-list-navigation-width-wrap-content. The second answer worked for me.